# Where to put X11 (XQuartz) configuration on OS X?

Tags: macos, xorg, xquartz

I’m trying to set the key repeat rate to a different value using `xset r rate 280 50`. I’ve tried adding this configuration statement to various configuration files (`~/.zprofile`, `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.zlogin`), but it always resulted in infinite crash loops when I tried to start XQuartz.app. It works fine if I remove the configuration files and use the `xset` statement in xterm directly instead.

```
XQuartz 2.7.8 (xorg-server 1.16.4)
OS X 10.11.1 (15B42)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent mailing-list item gives a clue ([Re: Newbie: XQuartz installation for FontForge questions](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/x11-users/2015/Aug/msg00008.html)):

> I suggest you just move it aside.  If you want to do things, drop scripts into ~/.xinitrc.d and set them executable.

and a little checking shows that if you put a script whose name suffixed ".sh" into your `~/.xinitrc.d` directory, you can put X commands (such as `xset`) there.  Be sure to end the commands with `&` (to detach).

For example, your `quick.sh` script might look like this:

```
xset r rate 10 &
```

However (noting comment), it is a little more involved than that.  Xquartz resets the keyboard rate *after* running the scripts in `/.xinitrc`.  Possibly this is related to a [bug report](http://xquartz-dev.macosforge.narkive.com/67V1HnGN/leopard-x11-2-3-2) resolved by making Xquartz match the system preferences.

As a workaround, you could make the `quick.sh` call a more complicated script:

```
pkill -9 rapid-keyboard
$HOME/.xinitrc.d/rapid-keyboard &
```

and (putting the new script in the same directory for convenience), the contents of `rapid-keyboard` could be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=\
/usr/bin:\
/bin:\
/opt/X11/bin

getvalue() {
    value=$(xset q |\
            fgrep "$2" |\
            sed -e 's/^.*'"$2"':[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]].*//')
    [ -z "$value" ] && value="not set"
    eval $1=$value
}

WANT_RATE=50
WANT_DELAY=280
LOGFILE=/tmp/rapid-keyboard.log
rm -f $LOGFILE

while :
do
    X11_PID=$(pgrep Xquartz)
    if [ -n "$X11_PID" ]
    then
            getvalue XSET_RATE "repeat rate"
            getvalue XSET_DELAY "repeat delay"
            if [ "x$XSET_RATE"  != "x$WANT_RATE" ]
            then
                    echo "** rate was $XSET_RATE at $(date)" >>$LOGFILE
                    xset r rate $WANT_DELAY $WANT_RATE
            elif [ "x$XSET_DELAY" != "x$WANT_DELAY" ]
            then
                    echo "** delay was $XSET_RATE at $(date)" >>$LOGFILE
                    xset r rate $WANT_DELAY $WANT_RATE
            fi
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

The script logs its changes (not really needed except for demonstration purposes), and waits for Xquartz to change the settings again.  In testing it, I see the settings change twice, during initialization, but not afterwards.

Comment: Scripts in ~/.xinitrc.d get ignored. Perhaps the settings gets overwritten when xterm starts or some such?

Comment: It has to be executable, and the name matters (I tested this before answering, using El Capitan with XQuartz 2.7.8).  However, I also ignore the first xterm, closing that, and run one that I compile myself -- order may matter (if the xinitrc script is run after xterm is started).

Comment: I've set the script in ~/.xinitrc.d/keyboard.sh to permission code 755. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: Could it be that the X11 server keeps running in the background so that just quitting and restarting XQuarts.app will not reload the configuration files? That seems unlikely since having the .initrc file existing causes the crash loop.

Comment: I see (revisiting).  The script is called but something in XQuartz follows and resets it.  According to pstree, xterm is already running. Will take a look later.

Comment: Interestingly, I've read elsewhere that `xset` should set it once and for all. Not sure this it true, but on my machine it certainly isn't. When I close and reopen XQuartz.app, it just reverts to the old key repeat settings.

Comment: Awesome. It works. Shall I file a bug somewhere?

Comment: You could [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=XQuartz&component=New%20Bugs).